# kendo-ui web: How to align subgrid columns to top level parent grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Please refer to plunk .
I want to align the sub grid columns to top level parent grid columns.
Any idea to achieve this.

Regards
Amit

Comment: plnker: http://plnkr.co/4GV5iotypUsbkFxdzcOB

Comment: i've the same issue, nobody can help ?